# how to get semantic ontology of words related to technology

Tags: data-request, linked-data, metadata, ontology

I would like to get some semantic ontology of words related to technology. Is there a way or a place I can get these kind of informations ?

Comment: What exactly should the ontology cover? "Technology" is very broad. Maybe you could provide some examples? Please also clarify the title of your question accordingly.

Comment: @PatrickHoefler I edited the title of my question

Answer (score 4):

The best place to start looking is [Linked Open Vocabularies](http://lov.okfn.org/). As of February 2015 they have indexed more than 450 vocabularies and ontologies and provide a convenient search feature.

Comment: in fact, the data available is not really as qualified as I would want. Do you know any other place to find these kind of ontology ?

Comment: As I already wrote in my other comment, it would be very helpful if you could add a specific example of what kind of data you would like to describe with this ontology.